# How to optimize dot leaders in HTML for Gmail iOS?

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

So, I am making some dot leaders for an email, using HTML tables.
Tried lot of options, and this one is the best so far.

The problem is that this piece of code works correctly everywhere (even in Outlook for Desktop), but not in Gmail app for iOS. It just ignores the line between words, and displays only words. Tried a lot of different approaches, but this one is the most reliable so far, because I also need it for MS Outlook .

Does anybody know how can I edit this code so the Gmail app on iOS would display it correctly?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="order-summary-item-container" colspan="2" style="
      border-collapse: collapse;
      line-height: 0;
      mso-table-lspace: 0;
      mso-table-rspace: 0;
      padding: 0;
      padding-bottom: 16px;
      ">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="
         border-collapse: collapse;
         border-spacing: 0;
         mso-table-lspace: 0;
         mso-table-rspace: 0;
         ">
        <tr>
          <td style="
               border-collapse: collapse;
               line-height: 120%;
               mso-table-lspace: 0;
               mso-table-rspace: 0;
               padding: 0;
               color: #7b8bad;
               font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
               font-size: 13px;
               font-weight: 500;
               white-space: nowrap;
               " class="caption">
            <span>Buyer</span>
          </td>
          <td style="
               border-collapse: collapse;
               line-height: 0;
               mso-table-lspace: 0;
               mso-table-rspace: 0;
               padding: 8px 8px 0;
               width: 100%;
               " width="100%">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="width: 100% !important;">
              <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top" width="600px" height="1" style="background-color: #cad1de; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 1px;">
                  <!--[if gte mso 15]>&nbsp;<![endif]-->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td class="subtitle2" style="
               border-collapse: collapse;
               line-height: 120%;
               mso-table-lspace: 0;
               mso-table-rspace: 0;
               padding: 0;
               color: #383c44;
               font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
               font-size: 15px;
               font-weight: 500;
               white-space: nowrap;
               ">
            <span>Buyer Name</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Gmail iOS 13.4.1 works for me...

Comment: Repaalce `&nbp;` with `&zwnj;` and remove the outlook conditional statement.\